# C# Read Multiple XML Files over a socket

Tags: c#, xml, sockets

I'm trying to figure out how to read multiple XML files over a socket.  Here is an example of what gets sent to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Message><Title>Title 1</Title><Content>Blah Blah</Content></Message>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Message><Title>Title 2</Title><Content>Blah Blah</Content></Message>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Message><Title>Title 3</Title><Content>Blah Blah</Content></Message>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Message><Title>Title 4</Title><Content>Blah Blah</Content></Message>
```

My problem is that some of these messages can take many calls to `Socket.Read()` to get to the `</Message> node.  Im trying to use XmlReader, but it fails on the 2nd` <?xml>` node.

I set `ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment`, but that doesn't appear to do anything.  Is there something else I have to do, or am I just going about this incorrectly?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the opposite of a fragment. There's no standard way to deal with this, and if the other side is already designed to send multiple XML documents without other delimiters, you're going to have to re-establish framing yourself, painfully, via parsing. Is there any chance the sender can be changed?

Comment: What you receive is text not XML. Process the text with tools to extract the XML fragments contained within the text

Comment: The tag protocol main idea with "open" and "close" tags is exactly to deal with fragments. So you know if the message is broken or you can parse it because it has an end well marked. This logic is present in a lot of RFC from Arnet to here (last 30/35 years). In this case this is not well formatted, until you know exactly how many messages do you get from this. If you can check this, then maybe you can "hop" the functional bug, but if not, you need a well XML formatted

Comment: I found this works - basically, I new up an XmlReader after successfully reading a node:
while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    await reader.ReadAsync();
                }

                var doc = await XDocument.LoadAsync(reader.ReadSubtree(), LoadOptions.None, token);

Basically, I'm reading a 'Message' node, and then creating a new XmlReader to read the next node

Comment: A fragment is inside one XML file.  You have multiple XML files.  Whenever you send data the receiver must know where the data ends.  There are three methods to do this 1) Send a terminating character at the end of the data that is not inside the data like EOT 2) Send a byte count at beginning of data and then read the exact number of bytes 3) Send fixed length data.